# Sencha Touch 2 - Changing Views after an Ajax.Request

Tags: sencha-touch-2

This may sound weird but ive been banging my head for the past 2 hours because of this problem. I have a function that triggers once I press a login button, when pressed it starts an Ajax Request.

```
 onEnter: function () {

      Ext.Viewport.mask();

      var email = Ext.getCmp('email').getValue();
      var pass = Ext.getCmp('pw').getValue();
      var consegui = 0;

      Ext.Ajax.request({

       controller: 'AP4.controller.MainCont',

          url: 'myurl',
           method: 'POST',
           callbackKey: 'callback',
          jsonData:{"username":'user', "password":'pass'},


          success: function(result) {
            //Se o webservice nao der erro ele entra aqui, nao quer dizer que tenha 
            //sido correctamente criado session
            // Unmask the viewport
            Ext.Viewport.unmask();
            Ext.Msg.alert("Login Done! Congrats!");
            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(this.getRegisto()); **//THIS LINE IS NOT WORKING**

          },         
          failure: function(result){       
            Ext.Msg.alert("Username ou Palavra passe Incorrectas!");        
          },

      });     
 },
```

For some reason, The setActiveItem is not working and I dont know why. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: the information is not full, what does `this.getRegisto()` return?

Comment: Please describe "is not working" better. Do you have any Javascript errors? Check your console.

Comment: Im sorry if was not clear enough. this.getRegisto() is a view Im tryin to call. What I want, after that Ajax.Request, is to change my view to Registo. it says that there is no such thing as getRegisto() ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are accessing `this.getRegisto;` function in wrong scope,
have you checked `this` keyword points to the object which you want in the success callback?

to change the scope of success callback you can simply add `scope` argument in the `Ext.Ajax.request` call, like this

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'myurl',
   method: 'POST',

   success: function(result) {
        // this will point to ViewPort object here
   },

   failure: function(result){
        Ext.Msg.alert("Username ou Palavra passe Incorrectas!");        
   },

   scope : Ext.Viewport     // this is used just for illustration, please specify correct scope here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If Registo is in your viewport, why not use setActiveItem(some number) like if Registro is the first item in your viewport then do setActiveItem(0);